# how to report the execution on a task to next processmessage?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I don't want to execute the current instructions in the current processmessage loop, but instead execute it in the next processmessage loop. Is their a good way to do it ? TThread.queue seam to be what i m looking for except that TThread.queue can not be executed from the main Thread :( I m under firemonkey also if it's matter

Comment: You don't want to call ProcessMessages at all surely.

Comment: i just want to stay in the mainthread :)

Comment: You don't want to call ProcessMessages.

Comment: `ProcessMessages` is evil. `ProcessMessages` does not belong anywhere. `ProcessMessages` strikes fear in the eyes of true developers. `ProcessMessages` screws things up to the point that it's difficult to debug. `ProcessMessages` must be avoided at all costs. `ProcessMessages` is called the "poor man's thread" and has a strong meaning. It is not a thread. Do not treat it as so. `ProcessMessages` is merely a distraction from the truth. The truth is, there is no `ProcessMessages`. The best applications are designed without `ProcessMessages`. They typically use background threads to do tasks.

Comment: Long story short, whenever you're compelled to use `Application.ProcessMessages`, you should seriously consider implementing a thread instead.

Comment: i agree with Jerry !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`TThread.Queue()` is asynchronous *only if* it is called in a worker thread. When `TThread.Queue()` is called in the main thread,  it is synchronous instead <sup>1</sup>.

To do what you are asking for, you can use [`TThread.CreateAnonymousThread()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TThread.CreateAnonymousThread) or [`TTask.Run()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Threading.TTask.Run) to create a worker thread that then calls `TThread.Queue()`.

<sup>1</sup>: please vote on [RSP-15427 Add an option to let TThread.Queue() run asynchronously when called by the main UI thread](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-15427).

Comment: thanks i vote ... yes so i was right, no other choice than TThread.CreateAnonymousThread() with inside TThread.Queue() :( it's a little heavy to create a thread just for this :(

Comment: See [Delayed action revisited](http://tech.turbu-rpg.com/454/delayed-action-revisited) for an example how to queue a `TProc()` to be executed later. It works by posting the method using `PostMessage()`, and executes in the next message loop.

Comment: @LURD that is a Windows-only solution. This question is tagged as FireMonkey, which likely implies that a cross-platform solution is needed.

Comment: @loki If you don't like `CreateAnonymousThread` you can always use `ITask` instead - this draws on a managed threadpool and can be lighter than explicitly creating a new thread each time.

Comment: @J... I did mention `TTask` (which implements `ITask`) in my answer. Also, `TTask` has known threading problems, it is not always better than using `TThread` directly.

Comment: Itask.TTask have many threading problems (like this one: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-15233) and i was force to remove all of them from my project.